# In VSCode the debugger for Ruby looks for files in wrong directory

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm starting to use Ruby on a Linux machine and use VSCode as my IDE. At first I installed Ruby 2.7.0 and I installed some extensions (via `gem install`) and did some practice. Then I installed Ruby 3.1.4. From the command line the version is ***3.1.4*** and the location is `/usr/local/bin`. Via `gem` I installed [libui](https://github.com/kojix2/LibUI) which was successfully installed in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/...`

I open VSCode to run a demo script but it fails because the debugger looks for `require libui` and returns:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- libui (LoadError).
```

I tried looking through the VSCode settings but there are so many and not always easy to interpret options that I got lost.

This is the `launch.json` file in VSCode:

```
{
     [
        {
            "name": "Debug Local File",
            "type": "Ruby",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I make VSCode look for Ruby 3.1.4 where I have installed libui instead of 2.7.0 where I do not have libui?

Comment: If I had to guess the 2.7 ruby is still in your PATH. would suggest installing a version manager of some sort and leveraging that. This will make your life significantly easier going forward. Recommendations include: `rvm`, `rbenv`, `asdf`, `chruby`, `frum`, etc.